# (React Native) update the 'fileduration' state for 'React-native-slider' upon fetching the audio file from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, slider, fetch

TL;DR

It is uncertain that when will the audio file be fetched and given to the trackplayer. So i need a way that will detect the change that the file has been fetched and duration value is now available. I tried playing around with Async/await but it still fails to deliver the duration value on time to the slider.

I am developing an RN app that can stream the audio files that are currently stored in my firebase storage. I am facing difficulty in updating the slider's `maximumValue`. Since the song takes a couple of seconds to get fetched from firebase, the (total) duration value of the song file given by the `react-native-track-player` is undefiend and consequently the play button's onPress function `setState(duration)` sets the new `tracklength` state as `undefined`. And this is set as the maximumValue for the slider, which in turn gives the error as shown in the screenshot.

What can i do such that, when the `TrackPlayer.getState()` (a method from the `ProgressComponent`) changes its value to '**playing**' or '**Ready**', the application automatically rerenders with the correct duration value without giving the error.
I have used `React-native-slider and React-native-Track-player`

```
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, Platform, StatusBar, Dimensions, Modal, Button } from 'react-native';
import Slider from 'react-native-slider';
import Moment from 'moment';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import { FontAwesome5, Feather, Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Surface, Card, Badge } from 'react-native-paper';
import TrackPlayer, { ProgressComponent, getPosition } from 'react-native-track-player';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

export default class MusicPlayer extends ProgressComponent {

    componentWillMount() {
        TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(async () => {
            await TrackPlayer.add({
                // url: 'https://sampleswap.org/mp3/artist/5101/Peppy--The-Firing-Squad_YMXB-160.mp3',
                url: (await storage().ref('Songs/01 - Luck Aazma - www.downloadming.com.mp3').getDownloadURL()).toString(),
            });
        }
        ).then(console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ' + this.getS().then(res => console.log(res))));
        // .then(async () => {
        //     var dur = (await TrackPlayer.getDuration()).toString();
        //     this.setState({ trackLength: dur });
        // });
        // const temp = await TrackPlayer.getState();
        // if (temp === TrackPlayer.STATE_READY) { console.log('its ready here') }
    }
    // componentDidMount() {
    //     this.interval = setInterval(
    //         () => {
    //             this.forceUpdate;
    //         }, 3500
    //     );
    // }
    // componentWillUnmount() {
    //     clearInterval(this.interval);
    // }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            trackLength: 300,
            timeElapsed: '0:00',
            timeRemaining: '5:00',
            optionsVisible: false,
            curr_time: 0,
            isPlaying: false,
            t_state: this.getS(),
        };
    }
    seekTime = seconds => {
        this.setState({ timeElapsed: Moment.utc(seconds * 1000).format('m:ss') });
        TrackPlayer.seekTo(seconds);
        this.setState({ timeRemaining: Moment.utc((this.state.trackLength - seconds) * 1000).format('m:ss') });
    };
    setCurr = seconds => {
        return Moment.utc(seconds * 1000).format('m:ss');
    };
    getS = async () => {
        return await TrackPlayer.getState();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: '#2d545e', flex: 1, paddingTop: (DeviceInfo.hasNotch && Platform.OS === 'android') ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0 }}>
                <View style={{ margin: 3, flex: 1 }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end', marginRight: 10 }}
                        onPress={this.toggleOverlay} >
                        <Entypo name="dots-three-vertical" size={24} color="white" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    {/* playlist name and album name */}
                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginTop: -25 }}>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF', fontSize: 10 }}>PLAYLIST</Text>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF', fontFamily: 'sans-serif', fontWeight: '500' }}>Album_name_here</Text>
                    </View>

                    {/* song image/ thumbnail zone */}
                    <Surface raised style={{ marginTop: 30, height: 200, width: 200, alignSelf: 'center', elevation: 50, borderRadius: 30 }}>
                        <Image source={{ uri: 'https://a10.gaanacdn.com/images/albums/61/161/crop_480x480_161.jpg' } || require('../../assets/images/temp.jpeg')} style={{ height: 200, width: 200, borderRadius: 30, alignSelf: 'center' }} />
                    </Surface>

                    {/* song name and artist name */}
                    <View style={{ marginTop: 25, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF', fontFamily: 'sans-serif', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20 }}>Song_Name_here</Text>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF', fontFamily: 'sans-serif', fontWeight: '500', marginTop: 3 }}>artist_name_here</Text>
                    </View>

                    {/* slider component only */}
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 8 }}>
                        <Slider
                            minimumValue={0}
                            value={this.state.position}
                            animationType="timing"
                            maximumValue={this.state.trackLength}
                            trackStyle={{ width: Dimensions.get('screen').width - 50, height: 4 }}
                            thumbStyle={{ height: 20, width: 20, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
                            thumbTouchSize={{ width: 100, height: 40 }}
                            minimumTrackTintColor="#000000"
                            onSlidingComplete={seconds => { console.log(seconds); this.seekTime(seconds); }}
                        />
                        <View style={{ width: Dimensions.get('screen').width - 35, backgroundColor: '#', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                            <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>{this.setCurr(this.state.position)}</Text>
                            <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>{this.setCurr(this.state.trackLength)}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>

                    {/* repeat, back, play, forward and shuffle button */}
                    <View style={{ width: '95%', height: 70, backgroundColor: '#', alignSelf: 'center', margin: 15, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, height: 30, width: 10, alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Feather
                                name="repeat"
                                size={30}
                                color="#000000"
                                style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, height: 30, width: 10, alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }} onPress={() => TrackPlayer.skipToPrevious()}>
                            <FontAwesome5 name="backward" size={32} color="#242320" style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        {
                            // this.state.t_state === TrackPlayer.STATE_READY && 
                            !this.state.isPlaying && <TouchableOpacity
                                style={{ flex: 1, height: 50, alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }}
                                onPress={async () => {
                                    TrackPlayer.play().then(this.setState({ isPlaying: true })).then(async () => {
                                        var dur = (await TrackPlayer.getDuration()).toString();
                                        this.setState({ trackLength: dur });
                                    });
                                }}
                            >
                                <FontAwesome5
                                    name="play"
                                    size={38}
                                    color="#000000"
                                    style={{ marginTop: 5 }}
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>}
                        {this.state.isPlaying && <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, height: 50, alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }} onPress={() => TrackPlayer.pause().then(this.setState({ isPlaying: false }))}>
                            <FontAwesome5
                                name="pause"
                                size={38}
                                color="#000000"
                                style={{ marginTop: 5 }}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>}
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, height: 30, width: 10, alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }} onPress={() => TrackPlayer.skipToNext()}>
                            <FontAwesome5 name="forward" size={32} color="#242320" style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, height: 30, width: 10, alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Entypo
                                name="shuffle"
                                size={30}
                                color="#000000"
                                style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                    {/* up next section */}
                    <Surface raised style={{ width: '95%', backgroundColor: 'black', alignSelf: 'center', height: 70, borderRadius: 10, marginTop: 5 }}>
                        <Card.Title
                            style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1, borderRadius: 10 }}
                            title={'Song Name here'}
                            titleStyle={{ margin: 25, padding: 0 }}
                            left={() =>
                                <Image
                                    style={{ width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 10, alignSelf: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}
                                    source={require('../../assets/images/temp.jpeg')}
                                />
                            }
                            leftStyle={{ alignItems: 'flex-start', margin: -10, padding: 0 }}
                            right={() => <Badge children={'Next'} size={30} style={{ width: 70, backgroundColor: 'black', borderRadius: 5, marginRight: 10 }} />}
                        />
                    </Surface>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>

        );
    }
}
```

Sorry for the messy code but the comments would help a bit in navigating to the main parts like **Slider and Play Button**

Error:
[My Error from the slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7QWz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For those who might require an answer to this, I solved the problem using React Hooks. `React Native Track Player` has a v2 update, in which the converting the above class component to functional component did the trick. It gives a rather accurate results then before. Refer to the [docs](https://react-native-track-player.js.org/documentation/#usetrackplayerprogress) here.